# Close current browser tab on button click, using reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Is there a way I can close the current browser tab with a press on the button, using reactjs?
I've tried `window.close()` and `self.close()` but none of the JavaScript methods seem to work.
I don't want the event of close window in React. I want to close the browser tab itself. `window.close()` can be used only when `window.open()` is used.

Comment: @MohammadMalek this event will be called when the user explicitly closes the browser tab. If i understood correctly. But i want to close the browser tab from a button click.

Comment: Because of security reasons, you can only close tabs you opened from your code, that's what the error message you pasted tells you

Answer (score 13):

It's not allowed by the browser to close not self open tab by `window.open()`
so it's kind of work around and convincing the browser it's open by you

> by open an empty page in the same page then close it.

You could try that

```
window.open("about:blank", "_self");
window.close();
```

Comment: Yeah... I thought the solution had to be a kind of trick like you mentioned, but I didn't know the exact code for opening the browser window that referred to the same window already opened indirectly by React or other file. I will try this.

Comment: This does exactly what is written above: opens an empty page in the same page and then closes the page. Only downside is that the empty page remains open (tested on Chrome 95).

Comment: Great - it works perfectly for me in chrome, edge & firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a way and it's not related to React but it is JavaScript.
You can create a function to call on button click if you want:

```
const closeTab = () => {
    window.opener = null;
    window.open("", "_self");
    window.close();
  };
<button onClick={closeTab}>Close Tab</button>
```

Comment: Your answer included the `window.opener` assignment which I found was actually necessary for this to work - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can close only these tabs which you generated by `window.open()` for now.

Comment: While true, definitely check out the other answers for some ways to close the current tab by briefly opening placeholder content - it ultimately has the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript can't close a window that it didn't directly open.

The script which opened the window must also be the script that closes the window. A new window isn't capable of closing itself via JavaScript. Here is an example below:

```
function openNewWindow() {
  window.open('www.ventrane.com');
}

function closeOpenedWindow() {
  window.close();
}
```

To open the page on a new tab, remove the self from  `window.open("", "_self");`

Answer (score -2):

The final answer is without opening a tab, you can't close it using window.close().
I have searched everywhere, so, I come up with a trick.
if you are using reactjs hooks, just open the same url in same tab using useEffect like this-

```
useEffect(() => {
window.open("https://xyz.abc/", "_self", "");
console.log("open window");
}, []);
```

Then make function of close and add onclick to close() which has `window.close();`

This will definitely work!
Tried and Tested.

Comment: isn't this a loop?

Comment: useEffect will cause window.open to run indefinitely since useEffect, even with [] dependency will be called everytime the window is loaded, no? This is what' im experiencing right now with your example

Comment: can you share on codepen or any online ide?

Comment: i tot it's pretty obvious it's a loop https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-bhaskara-pikd2?file=/src/App.js

Comment: try this, https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-thompson-x90rq?file=/src/App.js
but locally, because it won't close on sandbox,
so, when you run npm start, and then click on button, it will close.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial why i wrote xyz.abc, because when you deploy it on production, you deploy it on some website, and that website will replace https://xyz.abc/
and it will work fine after deployment.

Comment: when u write xyz.abc, the page will load, and then the useEffect will called as well. You can load the codesandbox URL in the window.open line, and u will see the loop. You cannot use window.open('samepage') in useEffect()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229382/discussion-between-prabhat-kumar-and-someone-special).